# Problem with reactive elements in RShiny?

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity

I have this line of code in my server.R which is causing problems:

```
int1_data[sample(nrow(int1_data), popint1(), seed), 'sb16s'] <- int1_data[sample(nrow(int1_data), popint1(), replace = F), 'sb16s']
```

My int1_data is reactive, my popint1 is reactive. Why is this causing the following error:

Warning: Error in : Operation not allowed without an active reactive context.

- You tried to do something that can only be done from inside a reactive consumer.
  57: 
  Error : Operation not allowed without an active reactive context.
- You tried to do something that can only be done from inside a reactive consumer.

Comment: The error is suggesting that you aren't running that piece of code inside a reactive environment. Is that the case?

Comment: Also, if `int1_data` is reactive, you should probably be using `int1_data()[...]`.  Without a reproducible example, it's going to be difficult to provide more precise advice.